# Kernel 5.7.0 in Ubuntu 18.04 causes ACPI errors

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, kernel

I just bought a Laptop with the new AMD Ryzen 7 4700u Processor and am trying to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows. I already had Ubuntu 20.04 installed and was able to run the newest Kernel (5.7.0) which is necessary to make Ubuntu work properly with the new AMD processors. Sadly I had to downgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 since I am working a lot with ROS melodic which only runs under 18.04. When I tried to run the Kernel 5.7.0 (or any other newer Kernel than 5.4.0) I get the following error:

```
[   0.364481] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPC0.E
C0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200326 /dswload2-162)
```

```
[   03644941] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200326/ps 
object-220)
```

```
[   0.796888] pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-VI: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
```

```
[   34688111] i2c_hid i2c-PNP0C50:00: failed to retrieve report from device. 
/dev/nume0n1p5: clean, 216874/1831424 files, 1530411/7324160 blocks
```

```
[   42676911] snd_pci_acp3x 0000:03:00.5: Invalid ACP audio node : 1
```

Maybe someone has an idea what to do about that?

Answer (score 1):

Mainline kernels are not officially supported by Ubuntu. You can use them for testing or if you need them to support some features unavailable in older kernels.

Unsupported kernels can throw all kinds of warnings and errors in Ubuntu. You can't do much with that. But if all works well, you can ignore it.

I don't see anything critical in the log.

BTW yesterday I installed Xubuntu on a Ryzen 3 3200u CPU and I have no problems on the 5.4 kernel.

Comment: Yeah the biggest issue for me is that i cant get an HDMI or display output with the older Kernel and programming on a 14inch screen is horrible :S

Comment: In a couple of months a new kernel will be officially introduced for 20.04.